# Cloud-Config - Hashed Password Being Set Incorrectly

Tags: ubuntu, password, provisioning, hash, cloud-config

I'm provisioning an Ubuntu 14.04 server with Digital Ocean and am using Cloud-Config in the user data field to do some initial setup. The issue I am having is creating a new user and setting a password with a SHA-512 hashed password string. Upon creation of the server, this new password does not work. When examining the `/etc/shadow` file, I find that the hashed password has been copied over with an erroneous `!` at the start of the hash. Example line from `/etc/shadow/` is as follows:

`jerry:!$6$rHazYJBiLiJ2$yZei93AcU9JlauoBV338kVMAOBk0b83iYtxw2/seXfTVuW0e6qtP4sL.ip9JVdnT3HbZ4620ql66WaEANJkg61:16855:0:99999:7:::`

Upon removing the `!` immediately after `jerry:`, the password works as expected.

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more research into the intricacies of Cloud-Config, I've found the issue. By default, the value of `lock-passwd` is set to True. This is what is causing the `!` to be added before the hashed password in `/etc/shadow`. Explicitly setting `lock-passwd` to False allows everything to sail along smoothly!